# How to access data in response body for RapidApi urban dictionary Android

Tags: android, rapidapi

I am getting response body  ** is
 **okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@6e33b4c** How to convert this to json or string.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
           Request request = new Request.Builder()
                   .url("https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term=check")
                   .get()
                   .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com")
                   .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", API)
                   .build();

           Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

           Log.d("TAG", "response:toString() " + response.toString());
           Log.d("TAG", "response:headers " + response.headers());
           Log.d("TAG", "response:body " + response.body());
           Log.d("TAG", "response:challenges " + response.challenges());
           Log.d("TAG", "response:message " + response.message());
```

Log

```
response:toString() Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term=check}

response:headers Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 13 Apr 2020 11:03:35 GMT
Server: RapidAPI-1.1.0
Via: 1.1 google
X-License: http://api.urbandictionary.com/
X-RapidAPI-Region: AWS - ap-southeast-1
X-RapidAPI-Version: 1.1.0
Content-Length: 4386
Connection: keep-alive

response:body okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@6e33b4c

response:challenges []

response:message OK
```

in RAPID API DEVELOPER DASHBOARD, I CAN SEE RESPONSE BODY How to convert it to string or JSON?
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using Retrofit? It will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would get the list in JSON

```
  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

  final JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("list");
```